# XCUITest How to access the tableView header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xctest

I'm new on `XCUItest` and I haven't found the method to access to the header of a `tableview`. I'm running my test on `Xcode 7.3` ...

My `UIView` is composed as follow

HEADER

- Label 1
- Label 2
- Image

CELL 1
....
....

CELL 2 
...
...

etc

To tap on the image inside the tableView header:

```
let header = app!.tables.otherElements.elementBoundByIndex(0).otherElements["label_header"]
let image_header = header.otherElements["image_header"]
product_image_header.tap()
```

Always fails with error :

> UI Testing Failure - No matches found for Other Query input was {(
>   Other 0x7fbd95c250e0: traits: 8590000128, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 120.0}}, label: 'image_header' )}

Have you a trick to have the full hierarchy of my view ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does this failure occur on the first line or the second line?

Comment: It's appear on the tap()

Comment: Are you able to tap the header element? This will help find the location of the problem.

Comment: With the xcode recorder yes I can tape on it. But if I use the line generate by the xcode recorder, I've the same issue ...

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have the same the issue ..

Answer (score -3):

try navigationBars

app.navigationBars["lable 1"].waitForExistence(timeout: 2)
app.navigationBars["lable 1"].tap

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how and where to implement this line?